# Is there any way we can use @BeforStep and @AfterStep annotations in Java?

Tags: java, automation, annotations, cucumber, gherkin

Is there any way we can use @BeforStep and @AfterStep annotations in Java with cucumber so that these functions get executed before and after each test step of a test.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.

Currently you only have @Before/@After which runs before/after each scenario.

If you want a hook for steps/scenarios/features/suite etc. you need to have a class such as your hooks class implement the Cucumber Formatter and Reporter interfaces.

When you implement those interfaces in your class, it will automatically import all the methods into that class that you will be Overriding, then just do a sysout in each method and you will see it automatically execute.

To get this to work, you will also need to add that file as a plugin in your CucumberOptions.

Have a look at this Hooks class:
https://github.com/GeeChao/stag-automation-reports-parent/blob/master/stag-extentreports/src/test/java/org/stag/steps/Hooks.java

Also see Runner class:
https://github.com/GeeChao/stag-automation-reports-parent/blob/master/stag-extentreports/src/test/java/org/stag/runner/RunCucumberTests.java